# What hooks do we have in order to do worker thread termination on application exit

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm spawning new worker threads from the 'main' thread of the application. These threads are constantly required to do some operation, as long as the application is alive. And, when the application exits, I do want all the worker threads to be cleaned up (whatever that means) properly. In order to do this, are life cycle methods the only place? Are there are intents/notifications which are received when an application exits ? If yes, can we register a broadcast receiver on such intents/notifications to do the required cleanup?

Thanks,

Ashok.

```
Code Snippet:
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SomeThreadTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Thread t = null;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                    Log.d("SomeThreadTest", "Thread wokeup now");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("SomeThreadTest", "Thread interrupted exception called!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    Log.d("SomeThreadTest", "I'm interrupted!");
                }
            }
        }
    }, "TestThread");

    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Consider calling workerThread.setDaemon(true) which tells the thread that is is a service provider and to KILL ME if the non daemon main thread quits.

Answer (score -1):

Android has daemon threads and shutdown hooks, which may help you here, since the application executes in it's own VM.

A daemon thread exits when the vm exits, and doesn't stop the vm from exiting. After creating a thread, call [thread.setDaemon(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) to mark the thread as a daemon thread. So, if you mark all your worker threads daemon threads, the VM will dispose of these threads when it exits.

Alternatively, a shutdown hook can be used to clean up the threads yourself when the vm exits. To register a shutdown hook, call [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29), passing a Thread that has not been started yet.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I did try this but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code snippet demonstrating the same. Can you point out if I'm missing something obvious here? I'm doing just the following in the onCreate lifecycle method & nothing else in the other methods at all. I'm posting the code snippet as part of the initial question as the comment section doesn't allow for more than 400 characters. That code seems to print 'Thread wokeup now' even after I come out of the application.

Comment: [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) says **Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that your code is run. Instead, you should use the most appropriate lifecycle notification (Activity.onPause, say).**